# How to use functions which present an API in terms of "topic" and "partition"?

Tags: rust, apache-kafka, rust-rdkafka

This is a question about how to use the Rust rdkafka APIs, most of which talk in terms of a topic name and partition number.

Consider this example API:

```
let metadata = consumer.fetch_watermarks(topic, partition, timeout);
```

The API takes a `partition` as well as a `topic`. This seems conceptually strange to me as I would expect most of the API to be agnostic to the particular partition number. I would expect most function calls to only care about partition names.

However, contrary to my assumptions, **many** of the rdkafka API calls talk in terms of both topics and partition indices.

So my question is - how should I be looking to use this? **In many cases, although I know the topic names which I wish to interact with, I don't necessarily know the details of the configuration, such as the number of partitions.**

Put another way, if I am to use such an API, I might likely need to **query in advance how many topics**, and possibly also what the set of valid partition `i32` indices are. (Although I expect it to start from zero and increase with no missing integer values, this might not necessarily be the case.)

---

To clarify one thing which I think was not clear before, Kafka topics, when split across multiple partitions, will have repeated values of the offset across those partitions.

Here's a quick sketch:

```
--------------
my_test_topic:
--------------

Partition Index 0: [0, 1, 2, 3]
Partition Index 1: [0, 1]
Partition Index 2: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Partition Index 3: []
```

As can be seen above, for example, Offset 1 exists across 3 Partitions.

So, I expect to **need** to query **all** of the `partition` index values, **but I don't know how to obtain this information in advance**. This is really the fundamental essence of my question. How do I know what the valid values of `partition: i32` (index) can be?

---

## Aside: Why are we doing this? Are we using Kafka "incorrectly"

This is really irrelevant information to the question, but I felt it necessary to include it because a comment was raised suggesting that what we are trying to do here is an incorrect use of Kafka.

- Are we using Kafka incorrectly?

In short - yes. But there is nothing I can do about this - at least not right now. Kafka is intended to be used for Microservices. Microservices are dynamically scalable logic blocks which can subscribe to a Kafka topic as part of a Consumer Group in order to process data in an offset-agnostic way. The Consumers should **never** need to know what the offset is. Nor should any logic require knowledge of the number of partitions.

- So why do we need this information?

What we are really doing is using Kafka as a message interchange system. We broadcast messages from one component to another using Kafka topics. We have multiple partitions, but we don't necessarily know how many, because we do not "own" or administrate the Kafka cluster.

When our components "die", they need to read the whole history of everything they sent out previously. This means they need to take a snapshot of what the watermarks are when they start up, and they need to detect when they have "read-past" the offset values on a *per-partition basis*.

That probably sounds like a bad design.

My personal opinion is that I would prefer to move towards a microservices architecture. For the particular system I am working on this isn't trivial, because the messages which are being sent to and from Kafka are not independent.

This means in some cases, there is no straight-forward way to move from using one processing unit to using a dynamic number of processing units.

Put another way, in some cases, we cannot use keys to split data into independent channels, because in order to construct the state of the system, a particular processor needs to read all the messages. It has to have a "global" view of the current state of the system.

---

To summarize: Until I have time to redesign the system, which I cannot do in a short period of time, we are stuck into this manner of using Kafka where we need to know about how many partitions exist for a topic and we also need to be able to obtain a snapshot of the current maximum offset on a per-topic basis, as well as recording this information from consumers as they consume data from a topic. (Again on a per-partition basis.)

I am aware this design does not use Kafka in the way it is intended to be used. Kafka was in use before I was hired - I hope the community can understand I cannot simply dictate that we delete it from the system and start again...

Comment: "So, I expect to need to query all of the partition index values" Usually Kafka consumers submit a [group ID](https://www.confluent.io/blog/configuring-apache-kafka-consumer-group-ids/) that lets kafka keep track of which records it has seen or not, letting the rdkafka library handle the complexity of partitioning. You can deal with individual partition offsets yourself, but its generally not needed.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo This is indeed correct. I will add explanation to the question as to why that route hasn't been taken ... yet ... but I suspect it will be rather lengthy and irrelevant information.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka tracks a lot of state, like offsets, on a per-partition basis, so that Kafka can scale to have multiple threads, processes, or even machines produce and consume in parallel, without needing to waste time synchronizing with each other.

Whether or not you need to care about partitions depends on your use case and scale. If you just want to produce or consume from a single process, the [rust-rdkafka examples](https://github.com/fede1024/rust-rdkafka/tree/master/examples) demonstrate how to do so, and don't involve individual partitions beyond printing them.

Otherwise, you can use [`fetch_metadata`](https://docs.rs/rdkafka/0.33.2/rdkafka/client/struct.Client.html#method.fetch_metadata) to get a list of topics, their partitions, and associated state.

Comment: Your answer has made me realize my question is worded confusingly. Thanks. I will update it